# How is an array of strings stored in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stl

When declaring an array of strings like `std::array<std::string, 5> myArray = ...`, how is it stored in memory?

In an array elements should be stored sequentially in memory but also any k-th element should be accessible by index in constant time, so, how does it work with variable length strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is normal array of fixed size `string` objects (sequentially in memory). The actual data of each string is allocated separately in another memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded `operator []` is available for `std::array`. Like normal arrays, std::array stores element sequentially. So, k-th element can still be accessed in constant time.

Comment: Be careful, storing elements sequentially does not ensure that random access is in constant time : think of a linked list.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Linklist does not store elements sequentially.

Comment: @pranitkothari Yes, it does. In the sense that they are in a well-defined sequence.

Comment: @juanchopanza We keep address of next node in previous node?

Comment: @pranitkothari That is one way to implement a linked list.

Comment: @juanchopanza Really confused, can you please provide any link.. I know this only difference between array and linked list.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is normally implemented as a pointer to some kind of variable-length storage. There is no magic in it. It can be stored in an array like any other *fixed size* object. The "variable size" part is an indirection away and the array is not concerned with it.

Answer (score -2):

I found the following:

> The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style
>   array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its
>   own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc.

In general knowing the memory layout of such structure is not important, but the complexity of accessor and modifiers. It is guaranteed that access is done in constant time. I suspect that behind the scene you have a C-array...

Comment: Not always important but that's kind of the point of the question

Comment: This can't be the point because you (in general) cannot directly access the structure!